# Random Number Generator and Graphs Algorithm

Tags: random, graph

Given a method to uniformly at random choose real numbers between 0 and 1, how would you use this random number generator to uniformly at random pick an edge in a graph `G` with `n` edges.
I know you can create a random graph `G` with the random number generator but I'm confused as how that can be modified to pick an random edge in a specific graph `G`.

Another question comes to mind. Given the graph `G` was now weighted, how would that algorithm change. I suppose now the weights would have more of a bearing on the edge chosen but how much would it change the algorithm

Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the un-weighted graph, assuming that edges are stored in a list, you could simply generate a uniform random integer between `1` and `n`. Most libraries (in any programming language) will have a uniform random number generator between 0 & 1 `u = U(0,1)`.

Now divide the `(0,1)` interval uniformly into `n` sub-intervals. for 'k' ranging from `1 to n-1` check in which interval `(k/n, (k+1)/n)` does `u` fall. `k` is your random edge.

For weighted graph, if the goal is to select an edge randomly based on its weight (higher weight implies more probable for selection), then use the same method as above. But divide the `(0,1)` interval into sub-interval based on their *weights*. Finally generate `u` and select `k`.

For ex: if there are 3 edges with weights {1,2,3}. Then divide `(0,1)` interval into 3 sub-interval in that proportion. ie: `(0,1/6)`, `(1/6,1/2)` and `(1/2,1)`. Generate `u` and find the interval in which it lies. Say `u=0.45`, then it lies in 2nd interval, so choose 2nd edge.

Comment: btw, which programming language are you using?

Comment: i was thinking of doing it in java, maybe C++